# Prove that $\sqrt{c^2-4}$ is irrational for all c > 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:** Prove that $\sqrt{c^2-4}$ is irrational for $c > 2$.

Context: I was watching the movie Old School and came across this problem in [one of the scenes of the movie](https://youtu.be/9CtebqN2IN4?t=44). I was wondering how to approach it - here's my approach so far.

**My attempt:** Factor $\sqrt{c^2-4}: \sqrt{(c-2)(c+2)}$. c must be an integer. I attempted using induction with a base case of $ c = 3$ and an inductive case of $ c = n+1$. Assuming that $\sqrt{(n-2)(n+2)}$ is irrational, WTS that $\sqrt{(n-1)(n+3)}$ is irrational. I'm stuck on where to go from here. Any hints or help are appreciated!

Comment: Hint: if integer $k$ is strictly between two consecutive perfect squares then $k$ cannot be a perfect square itself.

Comment: I don't think induction would be at your help. Instead, can you show that $c^2 -4$ can never be a perfect square? For that, assume  $c^2-4=a^2$ for some integer $a$, which would immediately imply $c^2-a^2 =4$ and then see what are the possibilities for $c$ and $a$.

Comment: @Gonçalo yes, edited. Thanks!

Comment: @YathirajSharma got it from there, thanks!

Comment: on the other hand, with rational $c=\frac{5}{2},$ we get $\sqrt{c^2 - 4}  =\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $c > 2$ is natural, suppose $p/q = \sqrt{c^{2} - 4} \in \mathbb{Q}$ for some $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p,q$ coprime. Then $p^{2}/q^{2} = c^{2} - 4$ and so $(c - p/q)(c + p/q) = 4$. Since we have all integers here, $c$ can only be $\pm 5/2$ or  $\pm 2$, each breaking an initial assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sqrt{c^2-4}$ is rational. It is easy to show if $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ is rational, then $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer (I suppose that $c$ in your question is a positive integer because this is a number theory problem).

Let $\sqrt{c^2-4}=n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$
c^2-4=n^2
$$

It implies that $c>n$, so $c \geq n+1$, then we have
$$
c^2-4 \geq (n+1)^2-4 = n^2+2n-3
$$

Note that $n^2+2n-3>n^2$ when $n \geq 2$, then $c^2-4 > n^2$, which is not possible. Thus, $n=0$ or $n=1$, then it is easy to check.

Comment: I do not think expression $c^2-2$ appears in this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, the answer has been modified now.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show $\sqrt{c^2-4}$ is rational iff it is an integer. We are given $c>2$, so let $\sqrt{c^2-4}=k\in \mathbb{N}^+$, which gives:

$$c^2-k^2=4\Rightarrow (c+k)(c-k)=4$$

So it means $(c+k)|4$, hence $c+k=1,2,4$, but $c>2,k\ge 1\Rightarrow c+k>3$, therefore $c+k=4$ and $c-k=1$, solve and we find $c=5/2, k=3/2$, they are not integers, hence we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c = \sqrt 5 > 2$ since $2^2=4<5$. Well, $\sqrt{5-4}=\sqrt 1 \in \mathbb Z$, so the answer is negative. There are countably many counter examples to this claim, but I won't show that here.

Comment: Except OP's "*$c$ must be an integer*".

Comment: @dxiv that was only in their attempt, I just read the question and immediately thought of a simple proof of the statement... well I suppose it is obvious what they were "Trying" to ask, in hindsight!

Comment: The OP wrote in a comment that it was meant to be part of the question, though, you're right, the edit put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

To make the explanation shorter, let us take it as a given that $\sqrt{n}$ is rational iff n is a square number (follows from $\sqrt{n} = k\sqrt{p_1p_2...p_j}$ and using a similar proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$).

Thus we need
$$c^2-4 = n^2$$
for $\sqrt{c^2-4}$ to be rational.

However, note that the distance between consecutive square numbers grows. $n^2-(n-1)^2 = 2n-1$ so for $c^2$ large enough $c^2-4$ will not 'reach' to the next lowest square number.